# Can't pass document id into a javascript function from handlebars

Tags: mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I've generated a list of items from the database and I would like to add a delete button to each entry for deletion of selected item. I know onclick takes an event but I'm not sure how to pass a database ID instead so I know which record to delete. Here is my template (handlebars):

```
<ul class="bill-list">
  {{#each bills}}
    <li>{{this.name}}</li>
    <button>Edit</button>
    <button onclick="deleteBill({{this._id}})">Delete</button>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

When I click delete, I get this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Is there some way to pull that data or id from event?

My function just console logs:

```
function deleteBill(bill) {
  console.log(bill);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet with your code you'll see that it should work:

```js
var obj = { "bills" : [{"_id":1,"name":"name1"},{"_id":2,"name":"name2"},{"_id":3,"name":"name3"}]};

var source   = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = template(obj);

function deleteBill(bill) {
  console.log(bill);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.js"></script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<ul class="bill-list">
{{#each bills}}
    <li>{{this.name}}
    <button>Edit</button>
    <button onclick="deleteBill({{this._id}})">Delete</button>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```